# listen for new email on exchange

Tags: java, exchangewebservices, ewsjavaapi

I am trying to use the ews-java API to connect to my inbox and listen for new emails.

I seem to be able to connect just fine, and I am copying code from the examples on github here:

https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/wiki/Getting-Started-Guide#beginsubscribetopushnotifications

```
// Subscribe to push notifications on the Inbox folder, and only listen
// to "new mail" events.
PushSubscription pushSubscription = service.SubscribeToPushNotifications(
    new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },
    new Uri("https://...") /* The endpoint of the listener. */,
    5 /* Get a status event every 5 minutes if no new events are available. */,
    null  /* watermark: null to start a new subscription. */,
    EventType.NewMail);
```

However this is the error in eclipse:

```
 new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },  // <---TYPE MISMATCH - CANNOT CONVERT FRM
WELLKNOWNFOLDERNAME TO FOLDERID
```

And also

```
EventType.NewMail);  // <---- NEWMAIL CANNOT BE RESOLVED OR IS NOT A FIELD
```

Its hard to sort this out because I cant find a manual on all the methods for this lib - and the example doesn't work.

The full code is:

```
package com.geekhelp.quickstart;

import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent.EventType;

import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.autodiscover.IAutodiscoverRedirectionUrl;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.ExchangeService;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.misc.ExchangeVersion;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.property.WellKnownFolderName;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.EmailMessage;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.service.item.Item;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.ExchangeCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.credential.WebCredentials;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.notification.PushSubscription;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.FolderId;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.property.complex.MessageBody;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.FindItemsResults;
import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.search.ItemView;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Running");
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
        ExchangeCredentials credentials = new WebCredentials("test@test.com0", "test");
        service.setCredentials(credentials);
        try {
            service.autodiscoverUrl("test@test.com");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println("Hello World");

        EmailMessage message;
        try {
            message = new EmailMessage(service);

            message.getToRecipients().add("test@test.com");
            message.setSubject("attachements");
            message.setBody(MessageBody.getMessageBodyFromText("Email attachements"));
            message.send();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        // Subscribe to push notifications on the Inbox folder, and only listen
        // to "new mail" events.
        PushSubscription pushSubscription = service.SubscribeToPushNotifications(
            new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox },  // <------------ TYPE MISMATCH - CANNOT CONVERT FRM
WELLKNOWNFOLDERNAME TO FOLDERID
            new java.net.URI("https://mail.test.com//EWS//Exchange.asmx") /* The endpoint of the listener. */,
            5 /* Get a status event every 5 minutes if no new events are available. */,
            null  /* watermark: null to start a new subscription. */,
            EventType.NewMail);  // <----------- NEWMAIL CANNOT BE RESOLVED OR IS NOT A FIELD
    }
```

Thanks.

UPDATE

Thanks, but I am still getting a error:

```
FolderId[] folderId = { new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox)};
PushSubscription pushSubscription = service.subscribeToPushNotifications( folderId , service.getUrl(), 5, null, EventType.NewMail);
```

subscribeToPushNotifications is underlined red, and the IDE says:

The method subscribeToPushNotifications(Iterable, URI, int, String, EventType...) in the type ExchangeService is not applicable for the arguments (FolderId[], URI, int, null, EventType)

Answer (score 2):

Two things:

1) To create `FolderId` from `WellKnownFolderName`, you have to use the [relevant constructor](https://github.com/OfficeDev/ews-java-api/blob/master/src/main/java/microsoft/exchange/webservices/data/property/complex/FolderId.java). So change:
`new FolderId[] { WellKnownFolderName.Inbox }` to:

`new FolderId[] { new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox) }`

Note: `new FolderId[] {..}` only creates an array. Then each item in the array has to be of `FolderId` type so we use the constructor `new FolderId(...)` and pass the `WellKnownFolderName` as argument.

2) You are importing the wrong `EventType` (possibly the fault of an autoimport feature of the IDE),
So change:
`import javax.swing.event.DocumentEvent.EventType;` to:

`import microsoft.exchange.webservices.data.core.enumeration.notification.EventType;`

Answer (score 0):

Late response, but looking at your updated issue, apparently, arrays do not count as Iterable objects. Lists, however, *do* count as Iterable objects. All you need do is convert your Array into a List using the Arrays.asList() method, providing your array as a parameter.